# CSS Selectors to Apply Border to h4

Tags: html, css

On http://adasportsandrackets.com/wordpress, I am trying to add CSS to add a border under the h4 heading "Best Sellers."  It's not working and it's not a caching issue as I've tried in the major browsers after deleting cache.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  best-sellers">
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<h4>Best Sellers</h4>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.best-sellers h4 {

border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 7px 0px;

}
```

I also tried:

```
.best-sellers {

border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 7px 0px;

}
```

Comment: There is a border underneath it. It **is** working. Put on your glasses, man.

Comment: @Keren Mine didn't work?

Comment: Hmmm....I'm not seeing it even when I zoom, and have cleared cache and hard refreshed on IE Mozilla and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```css
.page-template-template-home-default-php .wpb_wrapper h4 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
}
```

Or try:

```css
.best-sellers h4 {border-bottom: 5px solid #999;}
```

Comment: This worked for me on the border (I needed the best-sellers class because there are other parts of the page that share the other classes.)  However, I want some space between the bottom of the border and the product images below.  I have tried applying both a margin and padding with no luck:  `.best-sellers h4 {
border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
margin:20px;`
}

Comment: Did you try giving an `!important`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.wpb_wrapper h4 { border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;}
```

Or try adding a class to h4 e.g.

```
<h4 class="borderh4">Lol</h4>

.borderh4 {border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to select based on it's parent div class:

```
.wpb_wrapper h4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 7px 0px;
}
```

As the previous answer stated, if your parent div has multiple classes, you usually need to select both for it to grab the right element:

```
.wpb_wrapper.another_class h4 {}
```